# Play Framework 2.0 Websockets Messages

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm using Playframework 2.0.3 and WebSockets. I put all the WebSockets in an Akka Actor. If I receive a message (String) on the WebSocket.In channel I want to respond to it. I'd like to use "Messages" (i18n), but I get the error "There is no HTTP Context available from here."
Any idea of how to use the Messages not in side of a HTTP-Request but e.g. in a WebSocket.in callback method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just found it out myself:

I'm storing the Context on opening the WebSocket. Whenever I have to access Messages in my WebSocket I set the Threadlocal:

```
Context.current.set(context);
```

Afterwards I remove it from current thread.

```
Context.current.remove();
```

Comment: BUt from where have you got context in the first line?